# How to pass a list to a function in KornShell script?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, aix

I need to pass a list to a KornShell (ksh) function, something like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh

print_list ()
{
        Files=$1

        for file in $(Files);do
                echo $file
        done
}

LogFiles=`find . -type f -name "*.log"`

print_list $LogFiles
```

When I try to run only first element in the list gets printed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you happen to run ksh93, not ksh88, you can use that syntax which handle embedded spaces in file/directory names:

```
#!/bin/ksh

function print_list
{
  eval "a=( \"\${$1[@]}\" )"
  for file in "${a[@]}";do
    echo $file
  done
}

IFS=$'\n' LogFiles=( $(find . -type f -name "*.log") )
print_list LogFiles
```

and here is a ksh88 way, still using an array and handling spaces:

```
#!/bin/ksh

function print_list
{
  i=1
  while [ $i -lt $2 ]
  do
    file=$(eval echo \${$1[$i]})
    echo file=$file
    i=$((i+1))
  done
}

(
  IFS="
  "
  i=1
  find . -type f -name "*.log" |
  while read l
  do
    LogFiles[$i]=$l
    i=$((i+1))
  done
  print_list LogFiles $i
)
```

Comment: Okay, ksh88 suggestion added.

Comment: @Dima : @jlliagre 's suggestions are better than mine if you need to process files/paths with embedded spaces. I recommend giving this post the check mark. Also, If you having to use ksh88 then I suppose your `find` doesn't support the `-printf0` option (that would simplify your solution immensly. Search on S.O. for printf0 and you'll see a lot of good solutions. Check your `find ` man page to see if it supported on your system. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

2 things

Pass in your list inside dbl-quotes, i.e.

```
print_list "${LogFile}"
```

Also use the 'all elements' variable (${@}) in your function (there is probably a better name for this).

```
print_list ()
{   
        for file in "${@}";do
                echo $file
        done
}
```

(you may need to remove the dbl-quotes around `${@}`.

Note that `$(Files)` would need to be `$( echo ${Files} )`

Also if there are spaces in your filenames, this will require further work. It is widely discussed here on S.O., so don't be afraid to search for 'find printf0' for some appropriate solutions.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You definitely need to double quotes around `$@`, but you don't really need the braces.

Comment: Thanks a lot @shelter for helping me, the solution works, but can you please elaborate on why I need double quotes here `print_list "${LogFile}"`

When I run it with double quotes every file name gets printed on the same line. When I run it without double quotes each file name gets printed on a new line.

For the background, I will scp each file to the remote log server inside of the loop and change its extension... So it would be nice to know to know consequences of using/not using double quotes for this scenario.

Comment: ah yes, you're right. I was responding to the two separate problems I saw in your code and didn't integrate the answer. If you're using `${@}` in the function, then you can remove the dbl-quotes from `$LogFile`. Good luck.

Comment: Hmmm. just tested both ways. Neither handle spaces in file/path names. I recommend using @jlliagre 's technique and giving them the checkmark. Good luck.